# Use Bootstrap TouchSpin JS plugin without Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Prestashop 1.7 theme based on the default classic theme. I however switched from Bootstrap to UIKit. However, there is a Bootstrap plugin called bootstrap-touchspin.js compiled into the theme JS file.

However, it seems that it needs bootstrap.js to work. Is there a way of using this plugin without using the whole of bootstrap.min.js since the UIkit framework also loads its own JS file? What part of bootstrap does the plugin really need?

I don't want to load two large main JS files for Bootstrap and UIKit.
Below is the way the JS files are imported:

```
import 'expose-loader?Tether!tether';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
import 'flexibility';
import 'bootstrap-touchspin';
```

Answer (score 0):

All bootstrap plugin use JQuery, so all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included.

When you import bootstrap.js, you include all bootstrap components.

However you can include just one or more components. But don't forget include JQuery and if you want bootstrap css, you have to include bootstrap.css too.

**but Bootstrap.js is not essential**

Comment: Thanks. Let me explain again. jQuery is already included as part of Prestashop core. Because the theme is based on Bootstrap framework. Both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js were included. The bootstrap-touchspin.js is not part of bootstrap but a plugin by another developer. It is however a plugin for bootstrap and is said to require bootstrap to work. I want to use this plugin but I do not want to keep all of bootstrap since I am now using a different framework.